# How to remove the changebar from footnotes

Tags: formatting, footnotes, changes

I am using the `changebar` package to display a sideline along certain paragraphs for stylistic reasons.

The default behavior of `changebar` seems to be to show the sideline alongside footnotes as well as the paragraphs. I was wondering if there was an easy way to (i) show the sidebar along a paragraph in the body of the text while (ii) not showing the sidebar alongside in the footnotes of the paragraph.

I know I can insert `\cbend` before the start of each footnote and `\cbstart` after it, but the text I am working with is around 70 pages long and this seems like a rather cumbersome method, so I was wondering if there was an easier way to accomplish this.

In terms of code: is there an easy way to display the `changebar` alongside the main paragraph, but *not* alongside footnotes 1 and 2, *without* manually inserting `cbstart`/`cbend` around footnotes?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changebar}
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

{\cbstart}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor mauris id tortor interdum pharetra\footnote{This is the first footnote.}. Vestibulum sagittis facilisis augue quis viverra. Aenean gravida 
rutrum leo, vel tincidunt neque feugiat et. Morbi eu nulla nec lorem tristique viverra. Praesent nec odio at felis aliquet vestibulum vel a risus. Fusce quam est, eleifend et rutrum et, malesuada non ante. Class aptent taciti 
sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean pellentesque justo id sapien consequat dictum vel in sem. Fusce volutpat, diam eu egestas egestas, neque leo adipiscing velit, non fermentum 
erat purus eu nisl. Vestibulum vitae venenatis augue. Fusce tellus velit, aliquet non bibendum commodo, vulputate sed ipsum. Proin mollis\footnote{This is the second footnote.} bibendum tellus, porta sagittis ante lobortis quis. 
Cras neque elit, sollicitudin at tincidunt et, eleifend ac dui. Maecenas id metus sit amet velit ullamcorper mattis at sollicitudin neque. Sed ut euismod augue.{\cbend}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\footnotemark` inside the `\cbstart` ... `\cbend` group, and then `\footnotetext` outside it. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for this. This is an improvement, although it would still require quite a bit of manual re-arranging of the file (but it is easier than to bracket out all footnotes with cbstart/cbends). I was wondering if there is a way to do this automatically for the entire document without having to edit individual footnote markers (Sorry if this was not entirely clear).

Comment: It should be possible to collect the footnotes within the `\cb...` block and process them at the end (at `\cbend`). That would require a little work though, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `changebar` package internally uses `\ltx@footnotetext` (a replacement of the kernel `\@footnotetext` command) to include the bar if changebars are active, and if so, wraps the the footnote text in changebars. To "reverse" this behaviour, the following reassignment will do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=10cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{changebar}

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext\ltx@footnotetext
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

{\cbstart}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor mauris id tortor interdum pharetra\footnote{This is the first footnote.}. Vestibulum sagittis facilisis augue quis viverra. Aenean gravida 
rutrum leo, vel tincidunt neque feugiat et. Morbi eu nulla nec lorem tristique viverra. Praesent nec odio at felis aliquet vestibulum vel a risus. Fusce quam est, eleifend et rutrum et, malesuada non ante. Class aptent taciti 
sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean pellentesque justo id sapien consequat dictum vel in sem. Fusce volutpat, diam eu egestas egestas, neque leo adipiscing velit, non fermentum 
erat purus eu nisl. Vestibulum vitae venenatis augue. Fusce tellus velit, aliquet non bibendum commodo, vulputate sed ipsum. Proin mollis\footnote{This is the second footnote.} bibendum tellus, porta sagittis ante lobortis quis. 
Cras neque elit, sollicitudin at tincidunt et, eleifend ac dui. Maecenas id metus sit amet velit ullamcorper mattis at sollicitudin neque. Sed ut euismod augue.{\cbend}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is also the desired behaviour for footnotes inside a `minipage`, a similar reassignment for `\@mpfootnotetext` will be necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=18cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{changebar}

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext\ltx@footnotetext
\let\@mpfootnotetext\ltx@mpfootnotetext
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
{\cbstart}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor mauris id tortor interdum pharetra\footnote{This is the first footnote.}. Vestibulum sagittis facilisis augue quis viverra. Aenean gravida 
rutrum leo, vel tincidunt neque feugiat et. Morbi eu nulla nec lorem tristique viverra. Praesent nec odio at felis aliquet vestibulum vel a risus. Fusce quam est, eleifend et rutrum et, malesuada non ante. Class aptent taciti 
sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean pellentesque justo id sapien consequat dictum vel in sem. Fusce volutpat, diam eu egestas egestas, neque leo adipiscing velit, non fermentum 
erat purus eu nisl. Vestibulum vitae venenatis augue. Fusce tellus velit, aliquet non bibendum commodo, vulputate sed ipsum. Proin mollis\footnote{This is the second footnote.} bibendum tellus, porta sagittis ante lobortis quis. 
Cras neque elit, sollicitudin at tincidunt et, eleifend ac dui. Maecenas id metus sit amet velit ullamcorper mattis at sollicitudin neque. Sed ut euismod augue.{\cbend}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

{\cbstart}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor mauris id tortor interdum pharetra\footnote{This is the first footnote.}. Vestibulum sagittis facilisis augue quis viverra. Aenean gravida 
rutrum leo, vel tincidunt neque feugiat et. Morbi eu nulla nec lorem tristique viverra. Praesent nec odio at felis aliquet vestibulum vel a risus. Fusce quam est, eleifend et rutrum et, malesuada non ante. Class aptent taciti 
sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean pellentesque justo id sapien consequat dictum vel in sem. Fusce volutpat, diam eu egestas egestas, neque leo adipiscing velit, non fermentum 
erat purus eu nisl. Vestibulum vitae venenatis augue. Fusce tellus velit, aliquet non bibendum commodo, vulputate sed ipsum. Proin mollis\footnote{This is the second footnote.} bibendum tellus, porta sagittis ante lobortis quis. 
Cras neque elit, sollicitudin at tincidunt et, eleifend ac dui. Maecenas id metus sit amet velit ullamcorper mattis at sollicitudin neque. Sed ut euismod augue.{\cbend}

\end{document}
```

[image]